# Problem knitting in RStudio

Tags: unicode, input-encodings

LaTeX Error: Unicode character ^^[ (U+001B)
not set up for use with LaTeX.

keep getting this how do I fix?

Comment: character U+001B is the ESC escape control character. It  is possible you have this in your file, in which case delete it, or perhaps your file is not UTF-8 encoded, in which case specify the right encoding to `inputenc`

Comment: I tried to locate using DeclareUnicodeCharacter{U+001B}{FIX ME!!!!} but nothing came up?

Comment: `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{U+001B}{FIX ME!!!!}` would have given an error from U+  it should be `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{001B}{FIX ME!!!!}`

Comment: note even without that, the full latex error message, which you have not shown, will highlight the point in the tex file where the character appears, but you have not shown the tex either.